# .then chaining mongodb/nodejs not returning filled array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to return an array(childz) that takes in results of a looped mongoose query inside chained promises but when I consolelog results it still is an empty array. i did nesting thens before but i thought chaining it is much better but still i dont know how to return these async results properly.

SCHEMA:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var PK = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
var RK = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId;

var CommentSchema = Schema({
    body: {type: String},
    chapterId: {type: RK, ref: 'Chapter'},
    by: {type: RK, ref: 'User'},
    children: [{
        type: RK,
        ref: 'Comment'

     }]
}, {timestamps: true});
```

CODE:

```
commentController.reply = function(req,res){

  var commentList;
  var newComment = new Comment(req.body);
  newComment.save();
  //console.log(newComment);
  var commid = req.body.comid;
  var dataa;
  //console.log(req.body.comid);
  //console.log(req.body.body);
  //console.log(req.body.xxchid);
  //console.log(req.body.by);


  Comment.findByIdAndUpdate(
    commid,
    {$push: {children: newComment}},
    {new: true}, 
     function(err, post){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      } else{
         //console.log(post+"haha")


      }

     }


    )


    var childz = [];

    Comment.find({chapterId: req.body.xxchid}).then(function(data){

      //console.log(data+"data");
      dataa = data;
      //console.log(dataa+"dataa");


        }).then(function(){



        Comment.find({_id: commid}).then(function(onlydata){



                for(var i=0;i<onlydata[0].children.length;i++){



          Comment.find({_id: onlydata[0].children[i]}).then(function(onlydatac){



              childz.push(onlydatac[0].body);
              console.log(childz+"imchildz");//does print this as it should. shows all the elements appropriate



          })



        }


   })


}).then(function(result){

  console.log(result+"result");
  for(var i=0;i<childz.length;i++){         //doesnt print out anything. 
    console.log(childz[i]+"really"+i);
  }
  console.log(childz); //shows an empty array []
  return res.send({commentList: dataa, comidd: commid, childs: childz})

})

}
```

Comment: Return your promises and don't mix callback and promises.

Comment: what do i return and where.

Comment: The first then isn't going to work, You need to return a promise to trigger the next `then`. You cant just make an assignment

Comment: ok but how do i return the for loop and childz array to next then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes. First use of `Comment.findByIdAndUpdate` is using the callback interface and then you are calling a then on it too. Second you are not returning promises inside the then of "parent"  promises.

```
Comment.findByIdAndUpdate(commid, {$push: {children: newComment}}, {new: true})
.exec()
.then(post => {
    var childz = [];
    return Comment.find({chapterId: req.body.xxchid})
    .exec()
    .then(function(data){
            var dataa = data; // don't know the use of it
            return Comment.find({_id: commid})
            .exec()
            .then(onlydata => {
                    return Promise.all(onlydata[0].children.map(child => {
                            return Comment.find({_id: child})
                            .exec()
                            .then((onlydatac) => {
                                  childz.push(onlydatac[0].body);
                            });
                  }));
            });
            .then(() => {
                    return childz;
            });
    });
});
```

You can also use `async-await` to make things simpler to understand.

```
async function findChildz(commid) {
  const post = await Comment.findByIdAndUpdate(commid, {$push: {children: newComment}}, {new: true}).exec();
  const dataa = await Comment.find({chapterId: req.body.xxchid}).exec();
  const onlydata = await Comment.find({_id: commid}).exec();
  const childz = await Promise.all(onlydata[0].children.map(child => {
    return Comment.find({ _id: child })
    .exec()
    .then(onlydatac => {
      return onlydatac[0].body;
    });
  }));
  return childz;
}

// then you can simple call the async function like
findChildz(commid)
.then(childz => {
    // you get you childz array
});
```